# IJetCompact Database limit

Tags: visual-c++, ms-access

I'm using IJetCompact to compress/ repair an access 2003 database. It works fine with smaller database <100 MB but for db's which is more than <200MB, it crashes after executing for a while. Is there a limit to the database size that I can use ?

Comment: Found the issue... it just took 30 min to fix the issue :)

Comment: Could you please post the details about the issue (as an answer), and your resolution, for others to benefit from it?

Comment: Actually there was no issue. It just took more time to process that much data.

Comment: Ok, I must have misinterpreted your first comment, then.